# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry to bother you,

So i mixed APIs in my code in my first post, i figured it out and i checked my code, now everything is in MYSQL (not with MYSQLI and MYSQL as it was in my first post).

I've got another problem with my code, i've got the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in your code on line 8.

So here's my code, if someone could help me what to do, i would be thankful :)

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';
    include_once("apitest/Functions/GTServerInfo.php"); 

    $sql = "SELECT server FROM users WHERE userId = $_SESSION['userId']"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $ip=$row["server"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    mysql_close($con);



    if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {

            header("Location: index.php");

            exit;

    }

    ?>
```

Line 8:

```
 $sql = "SELECT server FROM users WHERE userId = $_SESSION['userId']";
```

Comment: Check for errors. Check if your connection was successful, check if your query failed...

Comment: Yes, do what @Rizier123 said.

Comment: How ? Sorry, don't close my accout, i am just newbie, at php.

Comment: In your `dbconnect.php` file, check for errors in database connection and also database selection if they are failing somewhere. Also, check for errors when you run the query using `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $_SESSION and not $_SESSiON, I corrected it below;

```
$sql = "SELECT server FROM users WHERE userId = $_SESSION['userId']";
```

Comment: Still no results fetched

Comment: Do you still have the syntax error?

Comment: At least that is resolved right?

Comment: No, i don't have the syntax error anymore, but no results are fetched now :(

Comment: Yes, results might not be fetched since we need to know what the value of $_SESSION['userId'] is and see if there is any value like that in the DB that matches that value for results to be searched. Try to var_dump($_SESSION['userId']) and check its value.

Comment: I made the mysql table myself, so there is "userId" for sure, but how to do that? Sorry, i'm not very proffessional at this.

Comment: PHP often points to a line but the error has happened before that. Id be interested in seeing in what is contained in the include file - GTServerInfo.php. Im betting that there is an error in there. Try die-ing after each line and check your error reporting.